# Error when attempting to run COM browser

Tags: python, pywin32

I installed Python 3.5.2 (4def2a2901a5) 64-bit and pywin32 v. 220.

When I tried running the COM browser from the PyWin window, I get the following error:

```
Failed to execute command:
from win32com.client import combrowse;combrowse.main()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 60, in __init__
    _LoadDicts()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 110, in _LoadDicts
    f = open(os.path.join(win32com.__gen_path__, "dicts.dat"), "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Program Files\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\win32com\\gen_py\\dicts.dat'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 143, in GetGeneratePath
    os.stat(fname)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Program Files\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\win32com\\gen_py\\__init__.py'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\toolmenu.py", line 103, in HandleToolCommand
    exec("%s\n" % pyCmd)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from . import gencache
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 666, in <module>
    __init__()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 62, in __init__
    Rebuild()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 653, in Rebuild
    _SaveDicts()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 69, in _SaveDicts
    f = open(os.path.join(GetGeneratePath(), "dicts.dat"), "wb")
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 145, in GetGeneratePath
    f = open(fname,"w")
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Program Files\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\win32com\\gen_py\\__init__.py'
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get info about your used com-ports?
This is not clear from your question...

If "yes", you can also simply

```
    import serial.tools.list_ports

    def scan_comports(self):        
        correct_port = 'none'
        ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
        for p in ports:
              print "%s %s"%(p[0], p[1])
              if str(p[1]).startswith("SomeComportName"):
                 correct_port = p[0]
```

As I dont know and never needed **"win32com.client"** for comport operations in python I cant help with this module (which doesnt matter for me as comports are serial ports..)

Comment: I am trying to use the Python for Windows extensions, part of which is a module named `win32com`, for connecting to and manipulating COM (Component Object Model) servers. The package has a graphical object browser, that allows seeing the methods and properties available on a given object. Thus, your answer while well-intentioned, is absolutely irrelevant. And if you don't know what `win32com.client` is used for, you can look it up first.

Comment: sorry I misunderstood "COM browser"